# UglifyJs error in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

My package.json has

```
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p"
  }
```

My webpack.config .json hasd

```
module:{
    rules:[
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        use:[
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins:[
    new UglifyJSPlugin({ uglifyOptions: {  } })
  ]
```

I added at the top **const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')**

But i am getting the error *ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (urlParts) [bundle.js:779,4]
webpack: Failed to compile*

---

#### Solved

I used new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({}) instead of external UglifyJsPlugin

Comment: Wow, I've been here a few days ago, you can go through different solutions in git. What i did is, I just revert back my `webpack-dev-server: ~2.7.1` and used `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({})` instead of external UglifyJsPlugin

Comment: Well, in my case I just forgot to npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev. It just works after that. :) :)

Comment: Nice to know that.

Comment: @raju Update your question about your fix